# Windows 10 keeps BSODing (UNEXPECTED _STORE_EXCEPTION)even after resetting the pc

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, bsod

I tired nearly every possible ways for this solution like booting windows 10 again through USB,resetting, removing dual boot etc.
Note: My PC shows "Harddisk Problem Detected" also so I doubt this might be the culprit. If yes, how do I fix this(Without changing the harddisk)?.

Comment: If your PC says it has a disk problem, you have to replace the disk. There's no way around that.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to do exactly that :( .

Comment: And now I did replace the drive. It works well now.

Answer (score 0):

Test if it's the hard disk by installing an OS (e.g. [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)) on a USB flash drive and *running* (not just booting) from it.

1. If the PC runs from the flash drive without BSOD, you know it's *not* a hardware issue.
2. Mount the HDD in the PC. [Check its SMART status.](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html) Since SMART status is just an indicator, you can [perform more thorough testing with Smartmontools.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)

Note that *if there is an issue with the HDD*, the faster you can install another and salvage data, the better. Disk drives often go from "a bit flaky" to completely unmountable in a short time.

Comment: Tried dual booting with UBUNTU 16.04 and this poped out "System Problem Detected". Well , this just happened once. So what do you think it is ? @DrMoishe Pippik

Comment: Dual-booting is still using your HDD. Try booting and running from USB.

Comment: Ohh sorry ! I forgot to mention that. Live booting any OS (I tried 3 : Kali linux,Fedora and Ubuntu 14.04) gave no such errors. This means I have to replace my HDD right? @DrMoishe Pippik

Comment: Use the Linux SMART checker and Smartmontools to evaluate the HDD -- it might be a few bad sectors or end-of-life. Do not *run* from the HDD, use the tools on the flash drive to evaluate the HDD.

Comment: Ok will try ... but as of now ... my laptop seems to work well  .... thanks ✌